# Could not send email because of delivery error

Tags: email-client

The warning I get is following:

> This is the mail system at host smtp.poczta.onet.pl.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
>   be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
>   delete your own text from the attached returned message.
>
> The mail system
>
> <.....................@aol.com>: host mailin-01.mx.aol.com[64.12.91.195] refused to talk to
>   me: 421 4.7.1 : (DYN:T1) https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes#421dynt1

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: yes, it was the replay from server in response email.

Comment: Normally you get some smtp error codes as well ... there is not enough information there to answer your question. Try emailing the postmaster.

Comment: @DavidPostill I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Any ideas how to solve this problem?

The link in the question explains what is happening:

> **421 DYN:T1**
>
> - The IP address you are sending from has been temporarily rate limited because it is not Whitelisted, unexpected increase in volume,
>     or poor IP reputation.

Source [AOL Error Codes](https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes#421dynt1)

Are you sending a lot of mail to AOL?

- It could be a temporary error. Try again later.
- Your IP address may be blacklisted. You can check your IP Address at https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

Comment: I could not send the email from two weeks... I think it is not temporary;( it is very important gor me to send that email as soon as possible.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Try sending it from another account - gmail for example.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk You can also speak to your ISP and ask them about it.